# Problems installing node and elm.Cant access folders due to permissions

Tags: permissions

Trying to change my current directory in Linux for windows to the /LocalState/rootfs/, but when I enter the cd rootfs command I receive the below message.

I have tried using `sudo su + cd directory` and `chmod u+rx,go-w /rootfs` but neither worked and I still received the same message

`-bash: cd: rootfs/: Permission denied`
expecting the root folder to change

Answer (score 0):

You could use my `pathlld` tool, to look at permissions, ownerships, mount status, etc. See https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?".